# Интерфейс администратора после изменения модели

Tags: python, django, django-admin

После изменения модели админка перестала показывать поля модели. То есть в общем списке они показываются, а при открытии какой-нибудь конкретной модели просто пустое окно админки с кнопками “удалить”, “сохранить” и т.п.
Изменения в модели тоже довольно простые: удалил поле `TextField`, добавил поле `ForeignKey`. Миграции сделал, в `admin.py` упоминание старого поля тоже удалил.

Код модели и соответствующая ей модель в админке приведены ниже.

```
class DocumentModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    url_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    text_document = models.ForeignKey(DocumentTextModel, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'Контент', db_index=True)
    #text_doc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'Контент')
    visible_left = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'Левый столбец', db_index=True)
    visible_right = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=u'Правый столбец', db_index=True)
    visible_middle = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=u'Центр главной страницы', db_index=True)
    changedate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=u'Дата изменения', db_index=True)

class DocumentAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['changedate']
    list_display = ('title', 'changedate', )
    list_filter = ('changedate')
    # resize CharField in Form
    formfield_overrides = {
        # Django enforces maximum field length of 14 onto 'title' field when user is editing in the change form
        models.CharField: {'widget': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'300'})},
    }
    # search in model
    search_fields = ['title', ]
```

Так же выкладываю скриншот админки:
[image: Пустой интерфейс]

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли перечислить поля модели в атрибуте `fields`:

```
class DocumentAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'url_address' ..)
```

Comment: Спасибо, поля появились. А можно тогда ещё вопрос, почему в остальных моделях без указания fields обычно всё работает? Просто получается, что там я некоторые поля скрываю через editable=False, а тут наоборот все поля скрыты и мне приходится прописывать, какие именно показать.

Comment: Да, тут опять возникла эта проблема. Если добавить в fields поле 'text_document', то страница опять становится пустой.

Comment: @LegalActs вы где то запутались, без `fields` поля всегда будут пустыми, а `text_document` это `ForeignKey` поле, оно по дефолту должно отображаться как список моделей `DocumentTextModel`

Comment: Если поля не указаны, то выводятся все поля, у которых нет editable=False или которые не AutoField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields

Comment: У вас какая-то проблема с отображением поля text_document в админке.

Comment: @LegalActs Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа). Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.